# Compressing video file with Java

Tags: java, algorithm

Is it possible to Huffman Encode video files? Also in order to encode the video file in Java will I require any API for reading the bytes of the video file or should a simple `BufferedReader` do the job?

Comment: Considering that `BufferedReader` is used to read **text**, you have quite a lot to learn before you'll be able to work with video in Java.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Huffman is a lossless compression algorithm. But: there are plenty of video-formats that automatically compress their data, so applying Huffman-Encoding is redundant, if you select a proper format. And your skill-level doesn't seem to be high enough to work with videos anyways.

Comment: True, I'm no expert but to generalize my question, I only meant to ask whether there is any chain stream like `BufferedReader` to read video files. @Kayaman

Comment: No. There's no `VideoInputStream` even though there is an `ImageInputStream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For video processing in Java you can use [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html).

Here is quick [Java Media Framework basics](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jmf/j-jmf.html)

Comment: death link, please provide more information and detail instead of link. Please refer community guidelines. Link sometimes can be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Compressing video in java you can use IVCompressor 
for more details go https://techgnious.github.io/IVCompressor/

simple code

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.techgnious</groupId>
        <artifactId>IVCompressor</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

public static void main(String[] args) throws VideoException, IOException {
    IVCompressor compressor = new IVCompressor();
    IVSize customRes = new IVSize();
    customRes.setWidth(400);
    customRes.setHeight(300);
    File file = new File("D:/Testing/20.mp4");
        compressor.reduceVideoSizeAndSaveToAPath(file,VideoFormats.MP4,ResizeResolution.R480P,"D:/Testing/Custome");
    }
```